# android studioでボタンクリック時に画面遷移させる方法

Tags: java, android, android-studio

## したいこと

ボタンクリック時に別の画面(activity_sub1)に遷移したい。

## 試したこと

MainActivityの@overrideが二つ発生して被ってるので、一つにまとめるとviewがエラーになる。
参考書を読んだりしたのですが、@overrideの扱い方が今一つ分からないです。

```
activitymainxml
//このボタンをクリックするとactivity_sub1に遷移
<Button
        android:id="@+id/toSub1Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="516dp"
        android:text="toSub1Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
```

```
MainActivityjava

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickButton(android.view.View view) {
    (別のボタンについてのメソッド。中略)
    }

 　　@Override　//上の１overrideと被ってるので削除してまとめると別のボタンのviewがエラーになる
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);　
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub1);

        Button returnButton = findViewById(R.id.returnButton);

        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
activitysub1xml

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="680dp"
        android:text="returnButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
```

```
SubActivity1java

public class SubActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub1);

        Button returnButton = findViewById(R.id.returnButton);

        returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
                SubActivity1.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
AndroidManifestxml

  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SubActivity1"
            android:label="string/app_name" > 
        </activity> //サブactivity追加
    </application>
```

#参考にしたサイト
https://qiita.com/QiitaD/items/1495f2f9839fe8706d31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

@Overrideアノテーション(注釈)とご入力されたコードで発生しているエラーに関するご質問ですね。

@Overrideはこのメソッドが継承元のクラスから継承され、オーバーライド(上書き)されていることを示します。あくまでこの注釈はコンパイラへの指令として働き、書く必要はありますがコードの実行内容には影響しません。

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/10/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

ここでは、@Overrideが複数あるのが問題ではなく、同じ名前のonCreate(Bundle) メソッドが複数同一クラス内に存在していることが頂いたソースコードでは問題となっています。それに対する対処法は、片方を消してまとめることですので、対処は正しいかと思います。

コードを拝見した限りですと、MainActivityでエラーが生じているのではないでしょうか。
こちらで直しを入れたものは以下になります。

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);　
        //activity_mainのレイアウトをContentViewに設定
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //activity_main内のtoSub1Buttonを取得
        Button gosubButton = findViewById(R.id.toSub1Button);
        //ボタンがクリックされた時の処理を追加
        gosubButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
               //Intentを利用して他のアクティビティに遷移する
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubActivity1.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    public void onClickButton(android.view.View view) {
    }
}
```

修正点は以下のとおりです

- onCreateをひとつにした。
- R.layout.activity_mainをコンテントビューとして読み込むようにした
- activity_mainに含まれているボタンを取得するようにした
- Intentを使用してstartActivityでSubActivity1クラスに遷移するようにした

個別に命令文やエラーの意味を確認して理解を進めてみてください。稼働するサンプルコードなどと比較して見比べるのもいいと思います。

Comment: 個別の命令文の意味をコメントで入れていただき、ありがとうございます！それぞれの意味をきちんと理解できていなかったので勉強になりました。修正点を元に、自分の書いたコードと比較して復習させていただきます。無事に画面の遷移させることが出来ました。ありがとうございます！